# Find the closest string match

Tags: c#, string, find

C# WinApp: Let's say I search for dtg but the items that I am searching in are dvg , dz, dxg ... so I want it to find dvg for me because it is closer to dtg that I was searching for.
I know there are some NP-hard algorithms for that but really  I do not want to spend a ton of time on this. is there any String methods that does something close to this? or can do it with a few extra liens of code?

Comment: What's your exact definition of similarity/proximity between strings? Or is anything good that can give you some sort of measure?

Comment: so for my example above, both the list of the strings and the string I am looking for start with "d" ... but next character for my search string is "t" ... in that list "t" is closer to "v" than to "z" or "x" , so I pick "dvg"  as a result of a search for "dtg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a Soundex.  If I can find a link to some code I'll get you some.  I did a spell checker using Soundexes, and it's exactly what you're looking for.

In the meantime, this google search should help:

http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+soundex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Here's a good C# implementation: http://www.builderau.com.au/program/csharp/print.htm?TYPE=story&AT=339291792-339028385t-320002002c

Answer (score 8):

You'd need a metric describing the difference between two strings. A common approach is to use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which is quickly implemented using a few lines of C# code (code files are available online).

Comment: I found a MSDN weblog implementation of it. but the whole algorithm is not what I need... Ok I was searching for "B" and in the list there were "AK" and "BOB" , guess what? algorithm is choosing "AK" ... darn it! at least just to "BOB" because they both start with it.... I mean the implementation was correct but the algorithm itself is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ClosestWord(string word, string[] terms)
{
    string term = word.ToLower();
    List<string> list = terms.ToList();
    if (list.Contains(term))
        return list.Find(t => t.ToLower() == term);
    else
    {
        int[] counter = new int[terms.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Math.Min(term.Length, terms[i].Length); x++)
            {
                int difference = Math.Abs(term[x] - terms[i][x]);
                counter[i] += difference;
            }
        }

        int min = counter.Min();
        int index = counter.ToList().FindIndex(t => t == min);
        return terms[index];
    }
}
```